# Generic observer pattern implementation in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11

Implemented observers in C++11 in a generic and statically accessible way. Though an instance is created, it's used only for cleanup and lifetime management.

```
template<typename... Args>
class Observers
{
private:
    unordered_map<int, vector<function<void(Args...)>>> observers;
    static Observers<Args...> *instance;
public:
    Observers()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    template<typename Observer>
    static void Register(int ev, Observer &&observer)
    {
        instance->observers[ev].push_back(forward<Observer>(observer));
    }

    static void Notify(int ev, Args... args)
    {
        try
        {
            auto &obs = instance->observers.at(ev);
            for (auto &o : obs)
                o(args...);
        }
        catch (...){}
    }
};

template<typename... Args>
Observers<Args...> *Observers<Args...>::instance;
```

usage:

```
using IntIntObservers = Observers < int, int > ;//optional type declaration

IntIntObservers o;//observer instance

IntIntObservers::Register(1, [=](int a, int b){whatever});

IntIntObservers::Notify(1, 4, 5);
```

An observer set can be accessed statically as long as the instance is alive. Multiple instances of the same type could be achieved by adding an id parameter to the template declaration, making it

```
template<int id, typename... Args>
```

Anything that I missed and could be improved?

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, I find the following:

- The current static behaviour is not *intuitive* (what does `int ev` really mean? why numbers and not names?), not *efficient* (why search in an `unordered map` rather that direct access?) and not *thread-safe* (`instance` is shared among all threads).
- A `list` might be more appropriate to store observers of one event, enabling easier management like *removing* an observer.
- Catching all *exceptions* in such a generic tool is a limitation. If needed, it could be at least parametrized.
- Parameter pack `Args...` does not take into account *return types*.
- Your `Notify` takes its arguments by value. Forwarding is not appropriate when calling multiple functions, but at least arguments should be passed *by reference*.

At a very basic level, I would prefer an object, called e.g. `signal`, templated on full function signature e.g. `R(A...)`, with non-static members:

- (private) `observers`: `std::list` or some associative container of `std::function<R(A...)>`
- `add()/remove()` or `connect()/disconnect()` to manage the content of `observers`. `remove()` would need some form of identification of existing observers, hence the need for an associative container.
- `operator()(A&&... a)` so that `signal` behaves like a function object. Arguments `a...` are passed without forwarding to underlying functions, so that they are copied if needed, and not invalidated between subsequent calls.
- additional management like `clear()/empty()`.

Your example usage would be rather like

```
signal<void(int, int)> s;
s.connect([=](int a, int b){whatever});
s(4, 5);
```

Isn't that better? Since everything is non-static, the user controls how many instances there are, and names them properly. In fact, a single object may have e.g. ten methods, each with its own observers. Each such method is then a signal and behaves like a function object.

Additionally

- `std::function` expects the 1st argument of a call to be the object if bound on a *member function*. It would be much more convenient to have functionality such that the object is stored separately and the `signal`'s signature matches exactly that of the member function. In many applications everything is about objects + member functions rather than free functions.
- Though non-trivial, possibly provide a mechanism to collect return values of called (observer) functions plus policies to choose, compute and return a single return value from `operator()`.

Have a look at [boost::signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals.html) and [boost::signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals2.html) for more ideas.

I have implemented my own model in the past, using [delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates) instead of `std::function`. There is an amazing amount of additional work if such "signals" are to fully mimic functions or member functions, including:

- default arguments (arbitrary values encoded into *types* in the signature itself)
- overloading (with different signatures)
- inheritance (overriding member functions in base/derived classes)
- virtual functions
- ...

I have used it as a full C++-compliant replacement for [Qt signals/slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) and wrapped most of the [Qt Gui module](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtgui.html) so that a project can be built without [moc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html) and without [qmake](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-manual.html). One day I will hopefully clean and rewrite in C++11.

Comment: In my experience, std::list is slower than std::vector, even when complexity says otherwise. Arrays are just that much faster on C++. The event type is an int because I felt like using enums, it could be a templated type.

Comment: @user1560102 `std::list`: depends on usage. Event "types": ok, let us put all our `double` variables of a program into a static `unordered_map<int, double>` called `DoubleVariables` and use a number instead of a name to `Register` or `Get` each variable as an entry in this map. How does this look? To me, it looks like assembly.